# Closed linear span of translations of simple step functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, approximation-theory

[This paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183506868) utilizes Wiener's tauberian theorem to indicate that the closed linear span of translations of any simple step function is equal to $L^p[a,b]$, where $1< p \leq \infty$ and $[a,b]$ are real finite constants.

However, I was under the impression that we could use the simple function approximation lemma to approximate any $L^1[a,b]$ function to arbitrary accuracy using translates of simple step functions.

My logic for this would be that the closed linear span of translates of a simple step function contains all simple functions, which are dense in $L^p[a,b]$ for $1\leq p<\infty$ from the simple function approximation lemma.

What is the error in my logic?

Comment: Why are the translates of a simple step function dense in the space of simple step functions?

Comment: I think my language was used incorrectly; what I meant to say is that the closed linear span of translates of a simple step function is the space of simple step functions, which are dense in the $L^p$ spaces mentioned above. Will edit to clarify.

Comment: "the closed linear span of translates of a simple step function is the space of simple step functions" is obviously false and doesn't appear to be what you mean to say.  Maybe you mean to say "the closed linear span of translates of a simple step function contains all simple functions"?  Note that simple functions are not the same thing as simple step functions!

Comment: Ack, that's precisely what I meant; apologies for the errors. Editing again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would the closed linear span of the translates of a single simple step function contain all simple functions?  This isn't obvious at all.  Consider the simple step function $1_{[0,1]}$.  How do you write the characteristic function $1_A$ of an arbitrary measurable set $A$ (of finite measure) as a limit of linear combinations of translates of $1_{[0,1]}$?

Comment: There are no counterexamples in $L^p$ for $p>1$ at least, by the result of the paper in question.  But my point is just that even in the cases where this statement is true, it is far from obvious and so your argument is very incomplete.

Comment: It seems clear that my thinking isn't clear on the subject, and that I've muddled different concepts; I should perhaps state a different less-unclear question on the matter and accept this one as resolved. Thank you for the help!